# When does it hold that $a^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[a]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

When does it hold that $a^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[a]$, for an algebraic number $a $? If $a$ is a root of unity of any order, done. But I know there are other examples: e.g., $2-\sqrt {3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that rearranging the minimal polynomial
$$
f(a) = c_na^n + c_{n-1}a^{n-1} + \ldots + c_1 a + c_0 = 0
$$
yields the formula
$$
a(c_na^{n-1} + c_{n-1}a^{n-2} + \ldots + c_1) = -c_0\\
a^{-1} = \left(\frac{-c_n}{c_0}\right)a^{n-1} + \left(\frac{-c_{n-1}}{c_0}\right)a^{n-2} + \ldots  + \left(\frac{-c_1}{c_0}\right)
$$
Assuming $f(x)$ was irreducible over $\Bbb Z[x]$ shows us that $a^{-1}$ lies in $\Bbb Z[a]$ precisely when the constant term $c_0 = \pm 1$.

Comment: Wow. I couldn't even guess the solution was simple like this.