# When does $\frac{\alpha^k-1}{\alpha-1}$ become a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha$ be a complex number. For which $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ does $\frac{\alpha^k-1}{\alpha-1}$ become a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$? If $\alpha=\xi_m$, an $m$-th primitive root of unity, then $\frac{\alpha^k-1}{\alpha-1}$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\xi_m]$ when $k$ and $m$ are relatively prime. Can I generalize this fact? Clearly, if $\alpha$ is transcendental, the only possible case is $k=1$. Thus we may assume $\alpha$ is an algebraic number.

(I posted a similar question [When does it hold that $a^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[a]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292481/when-does-it-hold-that-a-1-in-mathbbza) but I have another (anonymous?) ID since I have logged out temporally.)

complement:
Suppose the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $f(x)$. I guess $\frac{\alpha^k-1}{\alpha-1}$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ if and only if $f(\xi_k)=\beta$, where $\xi_k$ is a primitive $k$-th root of unity and $\beta$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\xi_k]$(or just a root of unity?). Is it correct? I think the "if" part is obtained just from the factorization of $f(x)$, but the "only if" part needs another justification.

Comment: The question is too general to have a useful answer, I think.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm a beginner so I don't know many results in this field. Then, for which $\alpha$, is there an integer $1\ne k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{\alpha^k-1}{\alpha-1}$ becomes a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$? Is this question meaningful?

Comment: Or, I think we may restrict the question more: for which $\alpha$, $\alpha+1$, $\alpha^2+\alpha+1$ or $\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1$ becomes a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$? Can I classify $\alpha$ for these elementary cases?

Comment: Hmm, if $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, then I guess $\alpha+1$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ iff $f(-1)=1$ or $-1$, by just a simple factorization of $f(x)$. Is it correct? For the higher degree cases, can I go further in similar fashion?